# Extended Fragment & List Fragment classes with SQLite query statements

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

Writing within a class extending a `Fragment`, `SQLite` query statements, is it possible?

*Problem@*

I am facing is that `SQLiteOpenHelper` requires a context as its parameter but its not possible to give context in `Fragment`.

I am also not able to access `Fragment elements from the Activity` as it is in another layout, can View Pager be used?

```
public class ListFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()); 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w("aaaaaaa","List on Create");
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w("b","List on Activity Created");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,false);

        TableRow leave =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.leave);
        leave.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.w("ccccccccc","List on Create View");
        TableRow time =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setOnClickListener(this);

        TableRow cart =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.cart);
        cart.setOnClickListener(this);

        TableRow invoice =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.invoice);
        invoice.setOnClickListener(this);

        TableRow purchase =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.purchase);
        purchase.setOnClickListener(this);

        TableRow travel =(TableRow)view.findViewById(R.id.travel);
        travel.setOnClickListener(this);



        TextView leave_n =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.leave_n);
        Cursor LCount= database.rawQuery("select count(*) from LeaveRequest",null); 
        LCount.moveToFirst(); 
        int lcount= LCount.getInt(0);
        LCount.close();
        leave_n.setText(""+lcount);


        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.leave:
                ArrayListFragment list=new ArrayListFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_capt, list);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;

        case R.id.time:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Toast message",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.cart:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Toast message",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

        case R.id.invoice:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Toast message",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

        case R.id.purchase:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Toast message",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.travel:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Toast message",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;


        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried `getParent()` in your fragment?

Comment: It is possible to give a context from a Fragment... you give the context of the activity containing the Fragment.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Comment: The SQLiteDBHelper is giving null ptr exception bcos it is not able to reseolve the context.....so wat can be the solution

Comment: I gave you the solution in my answer.  Use `getActivity()` in the call where it is looking for a context.  You also aren't opening the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it all the time... use `getActivity()`.

A code snippet from one of my ListFragments:

```
itemCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
getActivity().startManagingCursor(itemCursor);
String[] from = new String[] { GroceryDB.ITEM_NAME,
        GroceryDB.ITEM_UNIT, GroceryDB.ITEM_COST };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ListItem1, R.id.ListItem2, R.id.ListItem4 };
lists = new CursorAdapter_Check(getActivity(),
        R.layout.rowlayout_itemlist, itemCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(lists);
```

**EDIT**

You are getting errors because you never open your database and then try to get a cursor from a closed database.  Normally there should be something like this before you do anything with the database:

```
mDbHelper = new yourDatabase(getActivity());
mDbHelper.open();
```

Comment: wat is itemCursor, lists & CursorAdapter_Check in the snippet?

Comment: `itemCursor` is my Cursor holding the data from the DB to go into the list. `CursorAdapter_Check` is my customized/extended SimpleCursorAdapter.  (The customization is unrelated to your question... that could be a plain SimpleCursorAdapter).  The point is you supply the context to those things that need it from a Fragment by using `getActivity()`.